# Bound on number of inflexion points of projective curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a little problem and I want to be sure I found the correct answer:

For any integer $d\geq 2$, find an integer $f(d)\geq 0$ such that if $C\in\mathbb{P}^2$ is a projective curve of degree $d$, and $|\operatorname{Flex}(C)|<\infty$, then $|\operatorname{Flex}(C)|≤f(d)$.

My answer: If the degree of $C$ is $d$ then the degree of the Hessian is $3(d-2)$.
Now by Bezout's theorem, if the intersection is finite then the number of intersection points is the product of the degrees, i.e., $f(d)=3(d-2)d$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).